# android error when i try to put Array which contains Map<string, string> to String for my auto complete

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> c_tmp= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
public HashMap<String,String>mapa=new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] name_Val = null;

//i fill the map and the array list in a while()

mapa.put(numberz,nnn);
c_tmp.add(mapa);
```

and an error occurs( force close)when trying to fill the next line name_Val=....

```
name_Val = (String[]) c_tmp.toArray(new String[c_tmp.size()]);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name_Val);
txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

/// am I writing that line wrong ( because i've copied it from `ArrayList<String>`)

Comment: It would be better if you could show the Exception on that line too.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't still know where to look in the debbuger for the name of the exception...

Comment: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type Ljava/util/HashMap; cannot be stored in destination array of type [Ljava/lang/String;

probably this is?

Comment: Its under Eclipse>Window>Other>Android>Log Cat, and when you get a crash you would be indicated with Exception in `Red` you can paste that in here, for better understanding

Comment: Yes, it is because you have created an `Array List` of `Hash Maps` and then you are trying to get hold of `String Arrays`, whose conversion isn't possible, the way you are trying.

Comment: can u please refer me what should do or where to look for solving that

Comment: hi Tony,please see this [webtextr](http://code.google.com/p/webtextr/source/browse/trunk/Webtextr/src/com/nomcode/webtextr/MainActivity.java)  class i think this will help you??

Comment: one more [link](http://lemonbloggywog.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/customer-autocomplete-contacts-android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to do it first with a map and when you initialize it then to hash map, and use a simple adapter

```
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, peopleList, R.layout.row ,new String[] 
           { "Name", "Phone"  }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2  });
txtPhoneName.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But before all in another function populate the list of people...

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is, you can simply use a `HashMap<String,String>` Data type as map has the property of adding `values` for a `unique key`

After you are done with storing the Data in the `hashmap` you can use the `Iterator` to iterate and get all keys from the `HashMap` and thus the `Values` from all those keys which shall be Stored in an `ArrayList` , and then converting it to your `String Array` would not be a problem for you.

Comment: Iam sorry didn't realy get it:(, and about the map i tried first with a map but it doesnt want when i am initializin mapa=new Map<string,string>(); it shows error and that's why i change to hashmap